# What's the difference between 'violation' and 'infraction'?

Tags: word-difference

What's the difference between a violation and an infraction? I've checked the Webster's definitions and couldn't come up with anything better than a violation, unlike infraction, can be related to sports, but I am not sure.

Comment: [*violation*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/violation) has several definitions of which only one is similar to *infraction*. You checked a dictionary, but it would be helpful to add to your question what you found and what led to your question. Linking to an online dictionary might be helpful.

Comment: That conclusion is erroneous. At best, dictionaries can only **summarize** the full scope of a word's usage, so it's best to check **several** dictionaries., not just one, when trying to understand the subtle differences between two synonyms. For example, [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/infraction) shows definitions from four online dictionaries, and we can see that one definition of _infraction_ is: _A major violation of rules which leads to a penalty, if detected by the referee_ – so either word can be used in "relation to sports."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Infraction* is an instance or act of breaking a rule or law.

> Selling curved bananas is said to be an infraction of EU law.

You could also use *violation*, but that can also be used when someone is doing something that is morally wrong:

> He violated the peace of the church by shouting political slogans.

Generally "violation" can carry the nuance of something being not only illegal but also wrong.